# Test sql query for scalability without having large amount of data in the database tables

Tags: sql, performance, testing, db2, scalability

I have a pretty complicated SQL query (with multiple joins and xrefs) that is performing fine on the small data set that I have in my database tables. What I need to do is test to see how this query would work if the data set was substantially larger(possibly tens of thousands of records). What would be the best way to accomplish this? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Tens of thousands of records is not large...  Tens of thousands is extremely tiny.

Comment: There's no way to test without data. But *tens of thousand* should be no problem for a decent optimizer, for me *large* starts at a billion rows :-)

Answer (score 1):

There are options:

- Test on a large, realistic database.
- Simulate a large database: You can update the database statistics in the SYSSTAT views (see [here for all catalog views](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008443.html)). By setting the statistics to something that would mimick your large database you could test how the query plans change (or not). This will NOT give you performance numbers, only estimates on query costs and hopefully an idea of how well the queries are going to work.

Comment: If your production database has the same structure and hold more data db2look could be used to extract statistics from there and copy it over to your test system. Check out the "-m" option of db2look.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot test it realistically unless the rubber meets the road. I think you currently don't have a decent enough data volume so you are wondering would the query perform well if it comes to that volume. That's a genuine concern. I would agree with data_henrik that you should test on a large and realistic database. I would disagree faking it to simulate large dataset by updating stats.

Is your database fronted by an application from which the data is generated? If so I would suggest you use a load test framework (there are many available for free) to generate traffic to your application so you can seed your database with  records where you can test your query.